# Jquery $.post array (again...)

Tags: jquery, arrays, post

So, somewhat standard situation:

`OK, so replacing <div> with <form> works. Now to see if any nesting issues occur...`

```
<div id=hidden>
     <input type=hidden value=2 id=i1 name=i1>
     <input type=hidden value=5 id=i2 name=i2>
     <input type=hidden value=6 id=i3 name=i3>
     <input type=hidden value=1 id=i4 name=i4>
     <input type=hidden value=10 id=i5 name=i5>
</div>
```

I need to submit this data via POST. however `alert ($('#hidden').serialize());` returns blank string. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
alert($('#hidden input').serialize()); ​// this will serialize all input element.
```

if you want to `Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements`, use [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

from the Docs,

> **The [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form elements, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`.** *However, it is typically easier to select the `<form>` tag itself for serialization*

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w66qH/)

Comment: Did you mean to link to my exact fiddle, or make you own? :)

Answer (score 4):

Due to it's used of `.elements`, you can only [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) a `<form>` so change your `<div>` to a `<form>` and it'll work.

For illustration, [here's the `<div>` version](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KDSJ5/) (not working) and [the `<form>` version](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KDSJ5/1/) (working).

As an aside, make sure to enclose your attributes in quotes, like this:

```
<form id="hidden">
  <input type="hidden" value="2" id="i1" name="i1">
  <input type="hidden" value="5" id="i2" name="i2">
  <input type="hidden" value="6" id="i3" name="i3">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" id="i4" name="i4">
  <input type="hidden" value="10" id="i5" name="i5">
</form>​
```

---

An alternative is to break [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) down into [its parts](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L89), like this:

```
alert($.param($('#hidden :input').serializeArray()));
//or
alert($('#hidden :input').serialize());
```

[Check out that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KDSJ5/3/) (note it works with `<div>`).